# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream when debugging tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA and can't understand the cause for the following error when trying to debug unit tests:

*Error:gradle-resources-test:StorageService_test: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream when debugging tests in IntelliI IDEA*

although the code is building fine I can't debug because the debugger give me this error and fail to start.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the same error.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky no, It is just IntelliJ IDEA misbehaving. Sometimes "Invalidate cache and restart" helps.